# ngen build exited with code -1

Tags: c#

I have added `ngen` to my application under `project->property->Build even->post-build event` as `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install “$(TargetPath)”` to speed up first time startup but i get the following error message.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The command
>   "%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install
>   “\server\XXX\pdm\pdm\project\bin\Debug\project.exe”" exited
>   with code -1. project

C# Application property shows Target Framework `.Net Framework 4.5.2`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular quotes (`"`), not curly quotes (`“` and `”`). Command lines don't recognize curly quotes; they're for typesetting, not programming.

(The curly quotes show up in your error message too, so it's clear that you actually are using curly quotes and it wasn't some kind of copy/paste problem when you wrote your question.)

Comment: Joe I get the same error after applying your suggestion here is what i used `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install "$(TargetPath)"`